# Prevent User from changing query string

Tags: javascript, c#

In multi page application can we prevent user from skipping page by changing query string? If so How. Note: there are 13 pages but first 2-4 page (3 pages) are skipped by system if customer count ==1. If customer count is greater than 1 then none of the pages can(should) be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your question is complete; but in general terms, the query string only reflects the GET parameters. There is no way for an user to manipulate POST parameters without getting into the console. If the user can use console, no clientside data is safe; so to be foolproof, you would need to track the user in a serverside session.